# Popular Items webpart removes other webparts from page

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, search, search-driven-application

I have created a webpart page for search in sharepoint `/SitePages/`. I have added Search Box Webpart, Search Refinement Webpart and Search Results webpart. But whenever I drop Popular Items webpart, I lose other webpart's controls like this:

[image]

Ideally it should look like this:
[image]

Please let me know if i need to activate some feature or i am missing something,.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Per my test, I could not reproduce your issue on my end. The popular items web part works fine on my end. I think this issue could be related with your browser. Please try to use other browsers to check whether this issue exists.

Comment: i have other sharepoint site where i didn't face this issue. But on this instance i always face it, regardless of whatever browser i use

Comment: Have you tried other layouts? If you save the page, would that work?

Comment: it is happening only with searc-driven content category